# [OBJ-C][iOS] Getting floating point from NSArray - Problem

Tags: objective-c, ios, iphone-sdk-3.0, nsarray

I’ve recently stuck at a problem. Here is the thing, I’m trying to get a float object from NSArray that holds it, and all I can get is (null). Obviously not the thing that I want to receive. Look at the snippet of code:

```
h = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0],[NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0],[NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0], nil];
x = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0],[NSNumber numberWithFloat:2.0], nil]; 
y = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

int step = 15; // That is just a random value, will depend on size of h and x.

for (int i = 0; i < step; ++i) {
   NSLog(@"step = %i", i);


 NSMutableArray *xTemp = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:x];
 NSMutableArray *hTemp = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:h];

 for (int j = 0; j < 3; ++j) {

   float xToMul = [[xTemp objectAtIndex:j] floatValue];
   float hToMul = [[hTemp objectAtIndex:(j+i)] floatValue];

   NSLog(@"xToMul = %@", xToMul);
   NSLog(@"hToMul = %@", hToMul);


 }

   NSLog(@"\n");

}
```

And the resul is:

```
xToMul = (null)
hToMul = (null)
```

and all I need those values is to do some easy math.

Thanks.
M.R.

Answer (score 5):

Here's your problem:

```
float xToMul = [[xTemp objectAtIndex:j] floatValue]; float hToMul = [[hTemp objectAtIndex:(j+i)] floatValue];
NSLog(@"xToMul = %@", xToMul); NSLog(@"hToMul = %@", hToMul);
```

%@ is for objects that support -description. float is not an object at all. This code sends the float a -description message, which it can't respond to.

There's two ways to solve this.

The first is to make xToMul and hToMul objects instead of floats and keep the format string.

```
id xToMul = [xTemp objectAtIndex:j];
id hToMul = [hTemp objectAtIndex:(j+i)];
NSLog(@"xToMul = %@", xToMul);
NSLog(@"hToMul = %@", hToMul);
```

The second is to keep them as floats but fix the format string:

```
float xToMul = [[xTemp objectAtIndex:j] floatValue];
float hToMul = [[hTemp objectAtIndex:(j+i)] floatValue];
NSLog(@"xToMul = %f", xToMul);
NSLog(@"hToMul = %f", hToMul);
```

If you're planning to do math with the floats, you probably want to pick this option.

Another interesting point is this loop:

```
 for (int j = 0; j < 3; ++j) {
```

This will step through j with three values: 0, 1 and 2. That corresponds to the first, second and third item in NSArray. You have two items in `x` and three in `h`. I'm guessing this is just a simplification of your original code, but in both cases it's one short. j of 2+1 will access the 4th item in `h`, and j of 2 will access the 3rd item in `x`.

Comment: That solved my problem! Thank You a lot! And a really fast responce, impressive.

Comment: Be sure to check the checkbox next to the answer, giving credit where it's due and helping others find the right answer in the future.